# Не работает класс у Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Всем привет! Изучаю bootsrap. Всё работает отлично, кроме того момента, когда должен сработать col-sm-12. Есть вот такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        .row div {
            outline: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">1 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">2 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">3 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">4 of 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

При разных разрешения, все классы отрабатывают и ширина изменяется. Но col-sm-12 не срабатывает. Т.е., на мобильных экранах должен сработать col-sm-12 и блоки должны идти на всю ширину. А они остаются на маленьких разрешениях с классом col-md-6.
В чём ошибка?

[image: Вот пример результата]

Comment: Да работает же.. Вместо `.col-sm-12` можно смело ставить `.col-12`, что будет работать как и для меньше **sm** и для самого **sm**

Comment: Добавь еще col-12 ( col-sm-*  - для разрешений от 576 до 768, а для менее 576 используется col-* )

Comment: Я добавил скриншот.

Comment: Добавил класс col-12, но не помогло.
col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыли добавить viewport.

Добавьте:

> < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" >

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        .row div {
            outline: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">1 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">2 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">3 of 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">4 of 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS Подробнее [здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

Comment: Теперь всё работает! Спасибо!